# Prevent script execution until function has finished

Tags: ajax, wait, .post

I'm adding a Input type="text" dynamically:

```
elements.prepend('<input type="text" class="data form-control searchText" placeholder="'+lang(452)+'" />');
```

in Placeholder, calling a function "lang()" which gets the correct Placeholder for each Language from our Database:

```
function lang(id){
    $.post('gallery.php',{lang:id}).done(function(data){return data});
}
```

Now the placeholder always shows "undefined" because the script seems to be already finished before $.post gets ReadyState 4.

Somebody know how to achieve this?
Or has better Idea?

thank you

Answer (score 0):

Found out that it works by using the $.ajax function and setting async to false:

```
function lang(id){
    txt = '';
    $.ajax({url:'gallery.php', type:"POST", async:false, data:{lang:id}}).success(function(data){txt = data});
    return txt;
}
```

Note:
async only only works if url directs to local scripts.